# Remove from URL haproxy

Tags: haproxy, pfsense, regex

I have an haproxy server and I need it to rewrite the URL.

For example, I have a url that is like this:

```
http://myserver.com/UserName/signalr/connect...
```

and I need to remove the UserName, so when haproxy forwards to the server the url becomes:

```
http://myserver.com/signalr/connect...
```

if I know the UserName then this works:

```
reqrep ^([^\ ]*\ /)UserName[/]?(.*)     \1\2
```

My problem is that the UserName is not a static, but always in the same place in the URL, directly after the domain.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find a solution to this if anyone is interested

```
reqrep ^([^)((?:[^\/]*\/){1}[^\/]*\/(.*)     \1\2
```